# What is known, for given integers $k$, about existence of solutions to $a^n+b^n = c^n + k$ with $n>2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let's define "anti-Fermat numbers" as follows:

For $k \in Z$, $k$ is an anti-Fermat number if and only if there exist some $a,b,c$ and $n$ all in $Z^+$ with $n > 2$ such that $a^n + b^n = c^n + k$.  Let us say that $k$ is a pro-Fermat number iff $k$ is not an anti-Fermat number.

We know, for example, that $1$ is an anti-Fermat number since $9^3 + 10^3 = 12^3 + 1$. We also know that zero is a pro-Fermat number (Fermat's "last theorem"), although the proof is rather difficult.

What I'd like to know is whether anybody has done work on $a^n + b^n = c^n + k$ for $k\neq 0$?

- Are there any other known pro-Fermat numbers?
- Do we know anything about the asymptotic density of pro-Fermat or anti-Fermat numbers? By a heuristic probability argument, I strongly suspect that the density of anti-Fermat numbers near $M$ goes to $1$ as $M$ goes to infinity, but I've no clue how to make that rigorous.

Comment: A very naive search suggests that $2$ is "pro-Fermat", whereas $(-2)$ is "anti-Fermat".

Comment: In 2015, I conjectured that if $\{a,b,c\}$ is one of the multi-sets $\{2,3,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{2,3,5\}$ then any integer $k$ can be written as $x^a+y^b-z^c$ with $x,y,z$ positive integers. See http://oeis.org/A266277.

Comment: You may find Noam Elkies' page on Fermat near-misses to be interesting. http://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/ferm.html

Comment: Have you had a look at Elkies' page, Mark?

Comment: Are you still here, Mark?